# Page rss feeds display error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty

Tags: magento-1.9, rss-feed

I am using magento 1.9.2.4. I enabled rss feeds(New Products, Top Level Category) from the admin pannel. The rss feed for new products is working fine. But when I open any category rss page it display error as show in the picture.
the url open is like that . 
https://example.com/rss/catalog/category/cid/56/store_id/1/
[image]

Comment: Facing same issue in Magento 2. And not getting help on it. If anyone can help please let me know.